# Apply force/impulse to objects

Tags: python, physics, rigid-body-simulation, force-fields

I am trying to apply a force to certain objects via a self-made script.
Though I cannot find any option to do so in Blender. I could only find something equivalent in Blenders Game Engine: [applyImpulse()](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html).

The goal is to apply an impulse to objects with a minimum mass after they reached a specific coordinate.

If there is no such function like adding an impulse, then I could also try to manipulate the current movement vector of the object according to its previous frames, but they are only saved within the cache right? I am also not aware how to retrieve this data.

I was also trying to just use some sort of Force Fields, but they don't show the effect I wish.